# POST web request to dev machine running web server on localhost

Tags: c#, web, request

How would I go about sending a web request using the `HttpClient PostAsync()` method from my mobile app running on a windows tablet to my web app running on localhost on my desktop machine so that I can debug the server code?  What should the URL of the request consist of?

Comment: You need to configure a public IP on your machine that you could use in the URL on your phone or tablet.

Comment: Will running the following command in windows cmd on dev computer:
netsh http add urlacl url=http://testing:8080/ user=everyone

allow me to use http://testing:8080 as the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Than depend how is configure your network. if both the computer and the cell are in the same network (for example a wireless network at home) you can access your PC using the internal IP address assigned to it (in your Pc run ipconfig /all and see the IP address assigned to your computer)

Then you should create your URI using it, example:

http://192.168.xxx.xxxx/Your API controller

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...got it to work today with the help of a colleague.  Things were definitely more simple since all devices were connected to the same network.